# Average Function doesn't showing result properly in datatable in c#

Tags: c#

I'm making a function which group by 1 value and shows average results against group value. but when i write query in sql it shows average like this value(73.6868877912465). but when i get out average from c# using data table it gives this (4.59396937660475) value. Here is the code which i wrote first

```
protected DataTable Group(DataTable _dt)
    {
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        dTable.Columns.Add("Region_Name", typeof(string));
        dTable.Columns.Add("PercentComplete", typeof(Double));
        var query = from row in _dt.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<string>("Region_Name") into grp
                    let PercentComplete = grp.Select(r => r.Field<Double>("PercentComplete")).Count()
                    select new
                    {
                        Region_Name = grp.Key,
                        PercentComplete = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<Double>("PercentComplete"))/PercentComplete
                    };
        foreach (var grp in query)
        {


            dTable.Rows.Add(grp.Region_Name, grp.PercentComplete);


        }

        return dTable;

    }
```

and then i modified it:

```
protected DataTable Group(DataTable _dt)
    {
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        dTable.Columns.Add("Region_Name", typeof(string));
        dTable.Columns.Add("PercentComplete", typeof(Double));
        var query = from row in _dt.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<string>("Region_Name") into grp

                    select new
                    {
                        Region_Name = grp.Key,
                        PercentComplete = grp.Average(r => r.Field<Double>("PercentComplete"))
                    };
        foreach (var grp in query)
        {
            dTable.Rows.Add(grp.Region_Name, grp.PercentComplete);

        }

        return dTable;

    }
```

but both functions are producing same results. Kindly help me out of this 
problem.
This image is on web which shows average resuly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSXoR.png)

This Image is on Database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXMOG.png)

Comment: Can you add some sample input and show us results? It seams that everything is okay with this code.

Comment: Mr. @m.rogalski i added picture of result set kindly see them

Comment: First one is result image on web and second is query result...

Comment: Maybe instead of old linq try new one : `_dt.AsEnnumerable().GroupBy( e => e.Region_Name, e => e.PercentComplete)` then you can translate this to dictionary and use `foreach(var kvp in result) dTable.Rows.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Average());`

Comment: didn't work this one two :'(

Comment: didn't work this one too:-(

Comment: can you please convert your suggested code into running state. i'm trying but your code is not working

Comment: @m.rogalski can you please reply of this conversation

Comment: @m.rogalski Reults are different with this method but not as per requirement. Kindly guid me on this regard
        var query = _dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(e => e.Field<string>("Region_Name"))
                    .Select(e => new
                    {
                        Region_Name = e.Key,
                        PercentComplete = e.Average(r => r.Field<double>("PercentComplete"))
                    });
        foreach (var grp in query)
        {
            dTable.Rows.Add(grp.Region_Name, grp.PercentComplete);
        }

        return dTable;

Comment: @m.rogalski check it out please. it is giving error  protected DataTable 
        var query = _dt.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(e => e.Field<string>("GradeGroup"), e => e.Field<string>("Region_Name"))
                  .Select(e => new
                  {
                      GradeGroup = e.Key,
                      Region_Name=e.Key,
                      PercentComplete = e.Average(Field<double>("PercentComplete"))
                  });